# Spark error: "ERROR Utils: Exception while deleting Spark temp dir:"

Tags: scala, apache-spark, ioexception

**Edit:** adding details as requested

While running a simple Spark code written in Scala, locally on a Windows 7 64bit in Administrator mode, the execution always ends in an error as detailed below. The code does write the output as expected (`saveAsTextFile`) before throwing the error.

(Based on a google search, others have the same problem but adding `sc.stop()` at the end of the code as suggested on another board does not help.)

The code:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object Test {
    def main(args: Array[String]) { 
        System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:/prog/winutil/")   
        val inputFile1 = "./textinput.txt" 

        val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Testing")
        val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

        val data = sc.textFile(inputFile1)      

        val outputFile = "./output"
        data.saveAsTextFile(outputFile)

        sc.stop()       
    }
}
```

And the error message:

```
ERROR Utils: Exception while deleting Spark temp dir: [userpath]\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-a790ba3f-af1e-4d2b-80e8-4085caaad04b\userFiles
-904e004e-4ca2-43a8-8689-684cc401b827
java.io.IOException: Failed to delete: [userpath]\AppData\Local\Temp\spark
-a790ba3f-af1e-4d2b-80e8-4085caaad04b\userFiles-904e004e-4ca2-43a8-8689-684cc401
b827
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.deleteRecursively(Utils.scala:933)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anon$4$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV
$sp$2.apply(Utils.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anon$4$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV
$sp$2.apply(Utils.scala:179)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anon$4$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(Utils
.scala:179)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anon$4$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Utils.scala:
177)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anon$4$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Utils.scala:
177)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1618)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anon$4.run(Utils.scala:177)
```

Comment: Are you running in admin mode? Does the path get deleted (race condition)? What is your simple code? We need more details.

Comment: Added details, yes in admin mode, the temp path does not get deleted, code added above.

Comment: Have encountered the same issue on Windows 8.1 64-bit. I have read on the Spark mailing list that running the Spark Job on a command line with administrator permissions solves the issue but they didn't work for me.

Anyway, appears that this is a Bug in Spark 1.4.x (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-8333) that is being fixed/worked on at the moment.

Comment: still present in Spark 1.5.2

Comment: still present in Spark 2.1.1

Comment: still present in Spark 3.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Fixed for me after moving count() & take() statements on RDD before saving parquet using saveAsParquetFile. So try moving any rdd.take() before u call saveAsParquetFile.